# Response code 400 OKHTTP

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Am getting a **response code = 400** when i run my android app, but when i test the same URL in my browser and postman it has a response code of 200. What am I doing wrong. This is the get Request method

```
  public static String getRequest(String myUrl) throws IOException {

        InputStream is = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(myUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000 /*milliseconds*/);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(20000 /*milliseconds*/);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (response != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                is = conn.getErrorStream();
            else
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(response));


            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            return readStream(is);

            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please i need help.

Comment: you use local service?

Comment: no, am using an online server

Comment: the error 400 its bad request,check your values

Comment: Is there any Queryparam in your url or special HTTP header in your postman request

Comment: Does the code work correctly for other URLs?

Comment: when i test the same url on postman and my browser it works just fine

Comment: you need to show the postman request header and body

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call :

```
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true)
```

for GET requests. I think you're missing some headers like (Authorization)

Comment: He is getting 400 which  is bad request not unauthorized 401.

Comment: it works fine when i do a GET for any url but when i try to do a GET using oData filter query it gives me the error 400 . This is the url that is giving me the error 400 "http://housenaija.azurewebsites.net/api/PropertyListings?$filter=Price ge "+ minPrice+" and Price le "+maxPrice:  i will provide the minPrice and maxPrice value.

Answer (score 0):

so i found out the problem, since am using OData filter for the query and real devices devices cannot encode such URL I had to manually encode my URL.

This was what i was passing in before:

```
   String url = *Const.HOUSE_URL+"PropertyListings?$filter=Price ge "+ minPrice+" and Price le "+maxPrice*
```

but when encoded:  `String url = *Const.HOUSE_URL+"PropertyListings?$filter="+ **query** + minPrice+ **query1** + maxPrice;*`

where

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("Price ge ", "utf-8");

String query1 = URLEncoder.encode(" and Price le ","utf-8");
```

Then the final url that is passed into my HTTP GET request is:

```
 String url = Const.HOUSE_URL+"PropertyListings?$filter="+ query + minPrice+ query1 + maxPrice;
```

where minPrice and maxPrice are String values from an EditText.

Hope this helps some one.